# NAUDIO конвертация wav byte[] в mp3 byte[]

Tags: c#, naudio

Уже перепробовал куча вариантов. Мне по сети приходят байты WaveIn с голосом и передаются в эту функцию:

```
public static void Broadcast(byte[] data)
    {
        waveProvider.AddSamples(data, 0, data.Length);

        //TODO (save to) Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\out.mp3"
    }
```

Приходят примерно несколько десятков раз в секунду.
Вопрос такой: можно ли как-то эти байты преобразовать в MP3 кадр (Mp3Frame) [в приоритете] или хотя-бы этот кусочек со звуком как-то сохранить на диск? Перебрал разные варианты, все не подходят. 
Сейчас звук в виде:

```
internal static WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
internal static BufferedWaveProvider waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(8000, 2));
```

Он звучит в моих колонках, т.к. я использую

```
waveOut.Init(waveProvider);

waveOut.Play();
```

Рассмотрю любые варианты. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

то, что получилось и кое-как работает

```
public static void Broadcast(byte[] data)
    {
        r = new Mp3FileReader(WavToMP3(data));

        while ((frame = r.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
        {           
            foreach(Consumer c in WebCast.Clients) c.Audio(frame.RawData);

            Console.Title = frame.FrameLength.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static MemoryStream WavToMP3(byte[] wavFile)
    {
        using(var retMs = new MemoryStream())
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(wavFile))
        using(var rdr = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1)))
        using(var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(retMs, rdr.WaveFormat, 128))
        {
            rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
            wtr.Flush();
            return new MemoryStream(retMs.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас в BufferedWaveProvider формат (8000,2), а в RawSourceWaveStream передаете (44100, 16, 1), это точно правильно?

Comment: в данный момент buffered вообще убрал из кода, потому что он был для вывода через Play(), который я уже не использую

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вот здесь может быть проблема конвертации? как я понял, у mp3 другая частота дискретизации и кол-во кадров тоже отличается, а указал его значение я здесь. при установке 128 кадров для wav канала, он выводит ошибку, что максимум - 16, кое сейчас вообще должно и быть по умолчанию. Я не совсем понимаю принцип, может ли в этом быть дело. 
using(var rdr = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat(44100, 2)))  using(var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(retMs, rdr.WaveFormat, 128))
Еще не могу понять на каком этапе происходит сбой: при трансляции в сеть или при преобразовании

Comment: при попытке записать в wave буффер для прослушивания mp3 байты полученного аудио, waveOut выводит белый шум

Comment: Так какого все таки у вас формата семплы в массиве `byte[] data`? 44100 Гц моно или 8000 Гц стерео? Попробуйте для начала писать не в MP3, а в WAV файл и добиться, чтобы результат нормально воспроизводился проигрывателем.

Comment: через waveOut все воспроизводится без искажения. 44100 везде явно указаны, поэтому проблема явно где-то в битве за mp3

Comment: input.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 2);

Comment: Если у вас Windows 8+, можете попробовать вместо LameMP3FileWriter использовать MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3 (https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/MediaFoundationEncoder.md).

Comment: а у него данные входные ввиде файла и он туда же их и перезаписывает